# Compilation error: 'PCM' does not name a type; did you mean 'PC0'?

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide, pcm

> C:\Users\ownas\OneDrive\Documents\Arduino\0to9ver1\0to9ver1.ino:28:1: error: 'PCM' does not name a type; did you mean 'PC0'?
> PCM player;
> ^~~
> PC0
> C:\Users\ownas\OneDrive\Documents\Arduino\0to9ver1\0to9ver1.ino: In function 'void setup()':
> C:\Users\ownas\OneDrive\Documents\Arduino\0to9ver1\0to9ver1.ino:34:3: error: 'player' was not declared in this scope
> player.setPin(12); // setting pin 12 as the audio output pin
> ^~~~~~
> C:\Users\ownas\OneDrive\Documents\Arduino\0to9ver1\0to9ver1.ino:37:18: error: 'analogWriteResolution' was not declared in this scope
> Serial.println(analogWriteResolution(12)); //checking PWM support for pin 12
> ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> C:\Users\ownas\OneDrive\Documents\Arduino\0to9ver1\0to9ver1.ino:37:18: note: suggested alternative: 'analogWrite'
> Serial.println(analogWriteResolution(12)); //checking PWM support for pin 12
> ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> analogWrite
> C:\Users\ownas\OneDrive\Documents\Arduino\0to9ver1\0to9ver1.ino: In function 'void loop()':
> C:\Users\ownas\OneDrive\Documents\Arduino\0to9ver1\0to9ver1.ino:43:7: error: 'player' was not declared in this scope
> player.play_P(audioFiles[i]);
> ^~~~~~

exit status 1

Compilation error: 'PCM' does not name a type; did you mean 'PC0'?

```
#include <PCM.h>
#include <avr/pgmspace.h>

const int numButtons = 10;
const int buttons[numButtons] = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11}; // pin numbers for buttons
const int numAudioFiles = 10;
const char audio1[] PROGMEM = { ... }; // audio data for audio file 1
const char audio2[] PROGMEM = { ... }; // audio data for audio file 2
const char audio3[] PROGMEM = { ... }; // audio data for audio file 3
// and so on for audio files 4-10
const char* audioFiles[numAudioFiles] = {audio1, audio2, audio3, audio4, audio5, audio6, audio7, audio8, audio9, audio10}; // array of pointers to audio data
PCM player;

void setup() {
  for (int i = 0; i < numButtons; i++) {
    pinMode(buttons[i], INPUT);
  }
  player.setPin(12); // setting pin 12 as the audio output pin
  player.begin();
  Serial.println(F("PWM supported: "));
  Serial.println(analogWriteResolution(12)); //checking PWM support for pin 12
}

void loop() {
  for (int i = 0; i < numButtons; i++) {
    if (digitalRead(buttons[i]) == HIGH) {
      player.play_P(audioFiles[i]);
      while (player.isPlaying()); // wait for audio to finish
    }
  }
}
```

please help me with this

Comment: What is PCM, where does it come from?

Answer (score 1):

<PCM.h> Provides only two Methods and doesn't define a type named PCM.
Declaration of PCM in line 12 will Cause an Error.
What you're trying to achieve is
void startPlayback(unsigned char const *data, int length);

### The Syntax of PCM Playback is:

`startPlayback(Audio_file, sizeof(audioFiles[i]));`

> Comment out line 12, In this case 27th Line will be

`startPlayback(&audioFiles[i], sizeof(audioFiles[i]));`

Answer (score 0):

The PCM library does not define a PCM class.  Instead, it exports two functions:

```
void startPlayback(unsigned char const *data, int length);
void stopPlayback();
```

Note that this library is made to work with an Atmega168 at 16 MHz, and outputs on pin 11.